# Create Audio Media Player in Pjsip

Tags: android, git, android-studio, pjsip

When i try to create new audio player for pjsip that give me 7004 error 
i have try multiple paths but i dont able find the solution

Tryed to put .wav file in asset folder and give path accordingly but it does not work

```
 AudioMedia play_dev_med =MyApp.ep.audDevManager().getPlaybackDevMedia();
                    player=new AudioMediaPlayer();
                    player.createPlayer("audio_cutter.wav");
                    AudioMedia amp=AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(player);
```

i want create player which play .wav file but now it give below error

Title:       pjsua_player_create(&pj_name, options, &playerId)
Code:        70006
Description: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND)
Location:    ../src/pjsua2/media.cpp:279

Comment: You need to specify the folder name as well as the file name.

Comment: how to play second file with that player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue with ios class file we are in pjsip library so we need to provide the full path